# Get HttpServletRequest in Struts 2 interceptor

Tags: struts2, struts2-interceptors, actioncontext

To get the `HttpServletRequest` in an interceptor I used below code:

```
HttpServletRequest request =(HttpServletRequest) ActionContext.getContext().get(HTTP_REQUEST);
```

I tried to implement `ServletRequestAware` in the interceptor but it did not worked.

Are there any better ways to get `HttpServletRequest` in an Interceptor ?!

Comment: Why do you need `HttpServletRequest` in interceptor?

Comment: I want to develop and interceptor which prevents Ajax request from calling directly by url. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621539/how-to-determine-whether-a-request-is-ajax-or-normal.
This interceptor will be in interceptor stack which will prevent these requests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The servlet stuff you could get referencing `servletConfig` interceptor. After this interceptor is invoked you could get servlet stuff from `ServletActionContext`.

```
HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to use `ActionInvocation#getInvocationContext()` to retrieve your request.

```
public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
    ActionContext context = invocation.getInvocationContext();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.get(ServletActionContext.HTTP_REQUEST);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This should be approved answer for using inside interceptor.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) ActionContext.getContext()
                                               .get(ServletActionContext.HTTP_REQUEST);
```

it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

you will get ActionInvoction try `getInvocationContext()` it will return instance of "ActionContext" try `.get(HTTP_REQUEST);` on this.

or

use

```
ServletActionContext.getRequest()
```