# Is it possible to prevent GET calls for particular actions in Struts 2?

Tags: java, post, get, struts2

in my application I send all forms as POST request :

```
<s:form method="POST">
```

however I noticed when I prepare GET call like this:

```
www.domain.com?method:Save&param1=aa
```

proper action is invoked.

My question: is it possible to prevent GET calls for particular actions ?

So if I run `www.domain.com?method:Save&param1=aa` , action "Save" would not be invoked?

Comment: why you are practising with such outdated heavy weight frameworks? use Spring instead!

Comment: This project is quite old and big so this is reason why I still use struts..

Comment: Migration to another framework generate extra costs.. what is not acceptable for clients.

Comment: @ArifMustafa Besides not being a helpful comment, the idea that Spring is "lightweight" is a little silly. All S2 is is an alternative MVC web app system. I might not use it for new projects, but the argument that it's "heavy" doesn't match the reality.

Answer (score 0):

You can add interceptor to intercept the action and if the method is not POST then return error result. If you want to learn how to configure the result you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16875911/573032) answer.

In the interceptor implementation you can use `ServletActionContext.getRequest()` similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19241580/573032) answer.

Then use `request.getMethod()` to get the method of HTTP request.

Comment: Thanks I was thinking about this solution but I thought that there is another solution builded in framework.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you think you could add to the question. If you are using REST plugin then you have a mapping of http methods to actions.